# Get "does not implement methodSignatureForSelector" when try to store Array in NSUserDefaults,Swift?

Tags: swift

I try to store Array of objects in `NSUserDefaults`.

I have following snippets of code:

```
    var accounts = MyAccounts()
    var array:Array<MyAccounts.MyCalendar> =  accounts.populateFromCalendars()

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().
          setObject(array, forKey: "test_storeAccounts_array") // <- get error here
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

But I get Exception:

```
does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
```

---

my class structure:

```
class MyAccounts {

   /* ... */

    class MyCalendar {
        var title:String?
        var identifier:String?
        var email:String?
        var calType:String?
        var isActive:Bool?
        var isMainAcount:Bool?

        init(){}
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 105):

Make sure your class inherits from NSObject

```
class MyAccounts:NSObject {

   /* ... */

    class MyCalendar {
        var title:String?
        var identifier:String?
        var email:String?
        var calType:String?
        var isActive:Bool?
        var isMainAcount:Bool?

        init(){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why the error occurs when you don't inherit from `NSObject`? Seems to me that you could write a custom class, conform to the `NSCoding` protocol (implementing the 2 required methods), and there should be no problem. I don't understand why it is further necessary for your class to inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 26):

I was getting this exception in Swift 3.0. In my case, my model class was not inherit from NSObject base class. just inherit my class from NSObject base class and implements NSCoding protocol (if your container array has custom objects)

```
  class Stock: NSObject, NSCoding {

      var stockName: String?

      override init() {
      }

      //MARK: NSCoding protocol methods
      func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
          aCoder.encode(self.stockName, forKey: "name")
      }

      required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {

          if let name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String{
               self.stockName = name
          }
      }

      func getStockDataFromDict(stockDict stockDict:[String:AnyObject]) -> Stock {

           if let  stockName = stockDict["name"] {
                self.stockName = stockName as? String
           }

           return self
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, I experienced similar error while using the Notification Pattern within a custom class. Note that when the same notification(Observe) is implemented in a ViewController class , it doesn't complain. Its only with the custom class, created from a Swift file without subclassing this error was thrown

```
class myClass : NSObject {
      override init(){
            super.init()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("functionCall:"), name: "NotificationName", object: nil)
        }

    //Implement function
    func functionCall(notification: NSNotification) {

    //Extract the object and implement the function
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the class into `NSData` first. Something like this:

```
var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(accounts.populateFromCalendars())

var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
userDefaults.setObject(data, forKey: "test_storeAccounts_array");
```

Comment: It will work if array will be of type `NSMutableArray`. I have custom `Array<MyAccounts.MyCalendar>`. Get the same error. BTW I read your answer from comment

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment because I realised afterward it was written for a different problem.